# What to do when shell_exec(), proc_open(), etc are disabled and you can't change php.ini

Tags: symfony

I have installed symfony (3.2.7) on a new shared hosting and when i tried to use

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

I got a serie of

```
 Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons
```

When i tried to update via composer it was proc_open disabled...

So i'd like to know if there is any workaround to use the console on a shared hosting that disabled these functions. (i have no access to php.ini)

And if not, should i expect bad surprise if i develop on my computer and deploy on the server afterwards...
I already know that composer will not update online (i suppose i'll have to update on local then upload the files on the server), but is there anything else in symfony that could require a disabled function ?

(config.php only shows issue with a bad intl version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found how to do it !

Just add this before the command:

```
php -d disable_functions=''
```

For example

```
php -d disable_functions='' bin/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

More infos here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php